# Softmax regression for fashion mnist

Tags: python, numpy, softmax

I am trying to use softmax to solve fashion mnist. However, cost function always increases and it take a lot of time to run training. Please help me improve these lines of code. I did't know whether the vector dimension or the functions I write are correct. The x.shape is (784, 60000) and y.shape is (60000,). Thank you so much.

```
import numpy as np

num_px = x.shape[1]
x = np.array(x)
x_test = np.array(x_test)


x = (x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1).T) / 255
x_test = (x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], -1).T) / 255

print (y.shape)
print ("x's shape: " + str(x.shape))
print ("x_test's shape: " + str(x_test.shape))

def softmax(z):
    z -= np.max(z)
    sm = (np.exp(z).T / np.sum(np.exp(z), axis=1))
    return sm

def initialize(dim1):
    w = np.zeros((dim1, 1))
    b = 0
    return w, b

def propagate(w, b, X, Y):
    
    m = X.shape[1]  

    A = softmax((np.dot(w.T, X) + b))
    cost = (-1 / m) * np.sum(Y * np.log(A)) 
 
    # backwar prop
    dw = (1 / m) * np.dot(X, (A - Y))
    db = (1 / m) * np.sum(A - Y)

    cost = np.squeeze(cost)
    grads = {"dw": dw,
             "db": db}
    return grads, cost

def optimize(w, b, X, Y, num_iters, alpha, print_cost=False):
    costs = []
    for i in range(num_iters):
        grads, cost = propagate(w, b, X, Y)
        dw = grads["dw"]
        db = grads["db"]
        w = w - alpha * dw
        b = b - alpha * db

        if i % 50 == 0:
            costs.append(cost)

        # Print the cost every 100 training examples
        if print_cost and i % 50 == 0:
            print("Cost after iteration %i: %f" % (i, cost))

    params = {"w": w,
              "b": b}

    grads = {"dw": dw,
             "db": db}

    return params, grads, costs

def predict(w, b, X):
    y_pred = np.argmax(softmax((np.dot(w.T, X) + b)), axis=1)
    return y_pred

def model_LR(X_train, Y_train, test_x, test_y, num_iters, alpha, print_cost):
    
    w, b = initialize(X_train.shape[0])
    parameters, grads, costs = optimize(w, b, X_train, Y_train, num_iters, alpha, print_cost)

    w = parameters["w"]
    b = parameters["b"]

    y_prediction_train = predict(w, b, X_train)
    y_prediction_test = predict(w, b, test_x)
    print("Train accuracy: {} %", sum(y_prediction_train == Y_train[0]) / (float(len(Y_train))) * 100)
    print("Test accuracy: {} %", sum(y_prediction_test == test_y[0]) / (float(len(test_y))) * 100)

    d = {"costs": costs,
         "w": w,
         "b": b,
         "learning_rate": alpha,
         "num_iterations": num_iters}

    # Plot learning curve (with costs)
    costs = np.squeeze(d['costs'])
    plt.plot(costs)
    plt.ylabel('cost')
    plt.xlabel('iterations (per hundreds)')
    plt.title("Learning rate =" + str(d["learning_rate"]))
    plt.plot()
    plt.show()
    plt.close()

    return d
```

Comment: `z -= np.max(z)` Why this statement is there in softmax function?

Comment: Oh because When one of the z too big, the calculation exp ( z ) can cause overflow, which greatly affects the result of the softmax function. So one simple way to fix the overflow phenomenon is to subtract all of these z with large enough value. I think so

Comment: Which cost function you are trying to implement here? `BinaryCrossEntropy` or `Categorical CrossEntroypy`?

Comment: categorical_crossentropy

Comment: Then shouldn't the Y be a `oneHotVector` of size (60000, number-of-categories)?

Comment: So that mean the dimension of Y should be (6000,10) right ?

Comment: Right. You need to convert it to one hot vector.

Comment: Thank so much. I will try it

Comment: Oh and can you help me with my accuracy score. I can't implement it correct. It always equal 0%

Comment: What is the shape of your y_prediction_train?

Comment: y_prediction_train shape is (10,)

Comment: How? Should it has the number of examples also? (num_examples, 10)?

Comment: I don't know. I write the predict function return this  y_pred = np.argmax(softmax((np.dot(w.T, X) + b)), axis=1)

Comment: I can fix it when using this code:                                                                    
    y_prediction_train = to_categorical(y_prediction_train)
    y_prediction_test = to_categorical(y_prediction_test)

Comment: Use argmax to check for the correct prediction. acc = np.sum(np.argmax(y_train) == np.argmax(y_prediction))